# php- click/Action button multiple time base on value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a project where user can allocate ticket to another user. For now, when I click on the button it only allocates once. Now I want to input some value such that, when I click on allocate the it will add multiple data.

I used my method where I use java-script to execute the button on loop based on the value I insert in input-tag but this does not seem not work!
here are my code. :

```
                   <div class="col-5">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="allocate"
                                onclick="window.location.href = '{{ route('tickets.create', ['event' => $eventWithTickets->id, 'user' => Auth::user()->id]); multipleAllocation() }}'">
                            Allocate
                        </button>
                        <input id="allocate_no" type="number" placeholder="no to allocate ticket"></input>
                    </div>

        function multipleAllocation(){
        let i
        let allocate_no = document.getElementById("allocate_no")
        let btn_allocate = document.getElementById("allocate")
        let loop = allocate_no.value
        for(i=0;  i <loop; i++){
            btn_allocate.click();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function for ajax call to your route and instead of calling button click ,
like btn_allocate.click(); , call the ajax function .

`````
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="allocate"
       onclick="ajaxRequestToCreate()">Allocate</button>
     <input id="allocate_no" type="number" placeholder="no to allocate ticket</input>
</div>

function ajaxRequestToCreate(){
        let i
        let allocate_no = document.getElementById("allocate_no")
        let btn_allocate = document.getElementById("allocate")
        let loop = allocate_no.value
        for(i=0;  i <loop; i++){
            ajaxRequest();
        }````
`````

Comment: So my concept is right accept i just need to do ajax call to my creat route?